# Windows 10 update stuck on endless "Retry"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am trying to install the latest Windows update

> Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586

... and I am stuck in an endless Retry loop.

[image: Windows Update - problems installing some updates, we'll try again later]

Every time it tries to install this update, it fails with this message:

> There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help:
>
> (nothing printed here!)
>
> <kbd>Retry</kbd>

I've rebooted and retried a bunch of times and get the same exact result over and over, stuck on Retry:

[image: Windows Update -- failed to install over and over]

I have no idea what to try, or even how to get out of this endless update "problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later" retry loop. Suggestions welcome!

Disk partitions look like this, which I suspect may be the problem somehow:

[image: disk partitions]

Updates based on the answers and comments:

- This is a wired computer, no wifi, no battery
- Plenty of free space on the boot C:\ drive, almost 200GB
- There are no removable drives or USB keys attached
- Does have multiple drives (boot SSD and two large media HDDs)
- `sfc /scannow` reports good integrity
- Machine is Haswell based, 8GB RAM, built in mid 2013

> Update! 11-28-2015! After grabbing the, uh, ["fixed" version of this update](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/11/windows-10-november-update-mysteriously-pulled-as-concerns-about-bugs-grow/), it did finally install fine on this machine. There was a little weirdness where I had to reboot it in the middle, but otherwise it definitely worked, 10586 is installed now.

I will hopefully be able to provide an answer with the full set of troubleshooting from someone at Microsoft who helpfully assisted me in case anyone else runs into this.

Comment: Someone on Twitter said this happens for computers with multiple drives, and this computer does indeed have multiple drives, but I really don't want to disconnect them to try this theory out.

Comment: I had no issues with multiple drives, Mine's a sata SSD (an 850 pro) and two spinning rust drives though.

Comment: Does it actually try to install at all? On the machine I have managed to get it installed on Windows Update spent time downloading, then "preparing" during which there was more downloading, and then finally the reboot and install. Which stage is it failing at? How old is the machine? What do you see in C:\$windows.~bt\ ?

Comment: @mokubai it never gets to the reboot stage, it downloads, preps, fails. If only there was any kind of information about *why* it is failing...

Comment: Just a hunch but you *might* want to check the **system reserved partition** (not the primary partition) for (enough) space which I happened to run into today. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2015/08/10/windows-10-upgrade-couldn-t-update-the-system-reserved-partition.aspx) "fix".

Comment: I had no issues with multiple drives as well, just upgraded two machines with more than one drive. One computer has 4 SSDs plus two normal drives and everything went fine.

Comment: @JeffAtwood stop all the hassle and try the ISO upgrade

Comment: @JeffAtwood Had the exact same issue when upgrading to Win 10. The optional part did the trick and it didn't get stuck in the download,prep,fail loop. https://gist.github.com/matijagrcic/6cc656eac1cc16cb1a70 Helped several other people too.

Answer (score 7):

I had something similar.  Eventually it told me that it needed 10GB of free space on C: (not Pro version)

Comment: Actually I think this is a valid answer, I had a few people on Twitter say "I didn't have enough disk space and when I cleared some up it worked". However, I have almost 200gb free on the boot drive in this case..

Comment: Same here. But it offers to use another drive, which I've done. But even though it has plenty of space, it's still stuck in the same loop. I don't think anyone from MS has actually tested this :-(

Answer (score 6):

If the download always fails, [download the ISO from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench), mount the ISO into a virtual DVD drive (double click on ISO). Now run `setup.exe` and select upgrade.

To troubleshoot what went wrong during the upgrade, you have to look at the `setuperr.log` from `C:\$windows.~bt\sources\panther`.

*Gov Maharaj* from Microsoft [posted some known error codes/causes](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Windows-10-Upgrade-Tips-Microsoft-IoT-Starter-Kits-Windows-To-Go-and-more) in his [Defrag Show on channel9.msdn.com](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/). There is no general answer, we need to check the log files for each user.

Comment: This worked for me when on-line update didn't work.

Comment: I downloaded the ISO, but I get another mysterious "something happened" error when I try to install it. Looks like MS pulled this update altogether: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/11/windows-10-november-update-mysteriously-pulled-as-concerns-about-bugs-grow/

Comment: WZOR posted a hack to still get the TH2 ISO. Open the download site, open a JS command window and run this script: http://pastebin.com/EHrJZbsV http://www.win-10-forum.de/artikel-attachments/4199d1448276495-win-10-th2.jpg

Comment: MS offers now the ISO without any hacks again. So try it again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 when I install from the ISO (edit: using the "old" version of the update), I get a "something happened" error with no detail.

Comment: upload the folder **C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther** (zip file on OneDrive and post a share link here)

Comment: @JeffAtwood I posted a link to some errors/fixes

Answer (score 4):

Usually in cases like this there might be several items in play:

1. The update **was pulled**.
2. The update is simply **throttled** and therefore **temporarily unavailable**.
3. There is a **problem with the Windows Update configuration** on your machine.

It looks like at some point your update did install fine, so option 1 and 2 are the most likely culprits.

If something like this happens, it's super helpful for us to look at Panther logs, that can be located in:

```
C:\windows\panther
```

If that folder is empty, look at the logs here:

```
C:\$windows.~bt\sources\panther
```

The contents should be small enough to simply throw them in the ZIP and forward for analysis.

Now, there are also cases when there really is an issue with the OS configuration, and specifically with the **Windows Update** (*WU*) subsystem. In that case, it's worth trying the following:

1. Open Command Prompt (CMD) as admin.
2. Trigger the following commands sequentially:

*Batch Code:*

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop appidsvc
net stop cryptsvc
del "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat"
```

**bits** is the **Background Intelligent Transfer Service**.

**wuauserv** is the **Windows Update service**.

**appidsvc** is the **Application Identity service**, used by [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723678(v=ws.10).aspx).

**cryptsvc** is the **Cryptographic Services**, responsible for confirming signatures for Windows Files.

3. Time for some [RegSvr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32) magic to re-register core DLLs:

*Batch Code:*

```
cd /d %windir%\system32
regsvr32.exe atl.dll
regsvr32.exe urlmon.dll
regsvr32.exe mshtml.dll
regsvr32.exe shdocvw.dll
regsvr32.exe browseui.dll
regsvr32.exe jscript.dll
regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll
regsvr32.exe scrrun.dll
regsvr32.exe msxml.dll
regsvr32.exe msxml3.dll
regsvr32.exe msxml6.dll
regsvr32.exe actxprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe softpub.dll
regsvr32.exe wintrust.dll
regsvr32.exe dssenh.dll
regsvr32.exe rsaenh.dll
regsvr32.exe gpkcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe sccbase.dll
regsvr32.exe slbcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe cryptdlg.dll
regsvr32.exe oleaut32.dll
regsvr32.exe ole32.dll
regsvr32.exe shell32.dll
regsvr32.exe initpki.dll
regsvr32.exe wuapi.dll
regsvr32.exe wuaueng.dll
regsvr32.exe wuaueng1.dll
regsvr32.exe wucltui.dll
regsvr32.exe wups.dll
regsvr32.exe wups2.dll
regsvr32.exe wuweb.dll
regsvr32.exe qmgr.dll
regsvr32.exe qmgrprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe wucltux.dll
regsvr32.exe muweb.dll
regsvr32.exe wuwebv.dll
```

4. Reset WinSock:

*Batch Code:*

```
netsh winsock reset
```

5. [Reset the WinHTTP proxy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_3):

*Batch Code:*

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

6. Restore the previously disabled services:

*Batch Code:*

```
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
```

7. Reboot machine.
8. Check for updates once again.

All of the above can be wrapped in a single batch script to save time, but it's worth breaking them down 1-by-1.

Comment: sorry, this answer is crap, no matter if you are from MS or not. you have to check the setuperr.log before trying anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Like I already mentioned in the answer (and like you mentioned in the comment), we do need Panther logs to determine the source of any issues. `SetupErr.log` is part of that.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 Build 10240.  Here's what worked for me:

1. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/
2. Click on "Update Now"
3. This will download the upgrade tool, currently named 'Windows10Upgrade9252.exe'.
4. Run it as Adminitrator.

[Windows 10 Update Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEPK0.jpg)

This upgraded this specific laptop to Windows 10 Build 10516 (currently the latest build) and from then on Windows Update worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give a try to FixWin 10 software. However you may have to redownload the whole update.
2. Go to Microsoft's official website and download directly from there. Search Google for "Download Windows 10". The page maybe is the first one or second one. There you will have to use Media Creation Tool. If you don't want to download it using Media Creation tool and want direct ISO, download "User Agent Switcher" extension available for Chrome like web browsers. Select Mac Or Linux. Then the website will provide you with direct ISO files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: installing from the ISO produces a "something happened" install failed error.

Comment: Did you try unchecking "Give me updates for products same way when I update Windows" kind of check box? This option is present in Advanced Options. I know its a stupid idea but worked for me surprisingly.

Comment: The updated installer from Windows Update actually worked this time, just now tonight, so I _strongly_ suspect the previous update, the one that was pulled, was busted.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar `issue` when i was trying to install update `version 1511`. At first it was showing `storage` issue and asked for `external drive`. I selected location for my `D:` and then it downloaded the `update`. It was asking me to free up space minimum `10 GB` When it took only `4-5 GB` of `D:`. And when i restarted my system to install update my update installation failed and asked to download again that update

> Here's What i did to resolve problem

I downloaded new fresh `ISO` for `version 1511` with [Microsoft media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). And easily upgraded it without any problems

You don't need to boot it simply run `setup.exe` and skip `Downloading updates option`

> NOTE: When i used this tool about weeks ago it had bugs it was not showing different editions of Windows 10. It was just showing `WINDOWS 10`. If that happens with you choose different language from drop down and choose back the language you want then it will show you the options to choose between different editions of windows

You can also try to contact `WINDOWS TECHNICAL TEAM` via `CONTACT SUPPORT` app in Windows 10. Explain your problems they will definitely help you

I had problems with `activation` so i contacted them and they did solved my problem[I was not satisfied with there solution though]

Answer (score 0):

First update to the latest Windows build by running the Windows Update Assistant at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/

[image]
Note: this may **initially** trash your devices (it did for me big-time: no ethernet, no wifi, display stuck in low res with driver error message!).

**But: no worries**, that was just a means to an end because we straight away go to Settings and choose the option to **go back to the previous Windows build**:

[image]

That's it! Back in your familiar build, Windows Update now works fine. (And any devices trashed by the update are back to normal, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Windows really doesn't want to do the updates if the following services are disabled (maybe from some privacy tweaking tools or advice?)

Solution from windowsreport.com.

Here I copy the list of services:

citation:

Follow the instructions below to apply this workaround and hopefully resolve the issue at hand:

In the Search Windows bar, type services.msc and open Services.
Confirm that the following services on the list are set to run Automatic:

```
TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules
Server
Workstation
Automatic Updates OR Windows Update
Background Intelligent Transfer Service
```

Right-click on the each of these services and open Properties.
Make sure that they are set to Automatic.

AFTER THAT:

download the MEDIA CREATION TOOL

when asked set it to keep apps and data...

then let it run...

after a while you will be back on a working windows with all recent updates installed !

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a failed app installation on my Windows10 at work.  In order to end the repeated retries to install, I opened up the STORE and clicked on the Downloads and Updates icon that is just left of the search box at the top.  It basically looks like a downwards pointing arrow with a number beside it.

This lists all the apps that are queued for download and installation.  You should see a list of apps that have errors during download or installation.  To the far right of each item is a retry icon and an X icon.  Click the X to CANCEL the installation of whatever items are chronically failing.